# Is there a way to split a column of addresses if there is a sub address such as a unit number?

Tags: mysql

I have addresses listed in a column in one of my tables that are formatted as follows (address number in already in a separate column).

```
addressStreet
-----------------
S 1ST ST UNIT A
S 1ST ST UNIT 101
Main AVE H2
Brooklyn BLVD
Brooklyn BLVD 104
```

I am trying to figure out the best way of separating out the sub-address(UNIT#, ETC..) into a second column.

I am expecting to see

```
addressStreet       subStreet
--------------      ------------
S 1ST ST            UNIT A
S 1ST ST            UNIT 101
Main AVE            H2
Brooklyn BLVD
Brooklyn BLVD       104
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give on the issue.

Comment: So what the delimiter between `adressStreet` and `subStreet` ?

Comment: there isn't a single delimiter in the column. It would have to be spilt after the street type (AVE, RD, BLVD, ST...)

Comment: You have to be more precise. "Unit #, **ETC**" does not precisely describe how to split data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since the address data in your table do not have a specific delimiter, if your tags like `AVE,RD,ST,BLVD` are few,you can use `substring_index` in mysql to implement this, like below:

```
 select
     case when address like '% AVE%' then concat(substring_index(address,' AVE', 1), ' AVE')
          when address like '% ST%' then concat(substring_index(address,' ST', 1), ' ST')
          when address like '% RD%' then concat(substring_index(address,' RD', 1), ' RD')
          when address like '% BLVD%' then concat(substring_index(address,' BLVD', 1),' BLVD')  
     end as addressStreet,
     coalesce(case when address like '%AVE %' then substring_index(address,' AVE', -1)
          when address like '%ST %' then substring_index(address,' ST', -1)
          when address like '%RD %' then substring_index(address,' RD', -1)
          when address like '%BLVD %' then substring_index(address,' BLVD', -1)  
     end,'') as subStreet
 from
     street;
+---------------+-----------+
| addressStreet | subStreet |
+---------------+-----------+
| S 1ST ST      |  UNIT A   |
| S 1ST ST      |  UNIT 101 |
| Main AVE      |  H2       |
| Brooklyn BLVD |           |
| Brooklyn BLVD |  104      |
+---------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if you use PostgreSQL, things would be easier:

```
select 
    (regexp_split_to_array(address,' ST| AVE| BLVD| RD'))[1] as address_street,
    (regexp_split_to_array(address,' ST| AVE| BLVD| RD'))[2] as sub_street
from 
    street;;
 address_street | sub_street 
----------------+------------
 S 1ST          |  UNIT A
 S 1ST          |  UNIT 101
 Main           |  H2
 Brooklyn       | 
 Brooklyn       |  104
(5 rows)
```

Comment: If his delimeter is few and fix elements just like `AVE, RD, BLVD, ST`, I think that's ok.

Comment: So what about things like 'brave st'? While a valiant effort, the likelihood is that there are simply too many permutations to consider

Comment: Well, his data does not have a specific delimiter, so could you please tell us a better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, GIGO prevails in this instance.

Comment: Yep, according to his data, we can only to exhaust all tags as the delimiters to slove this problem as above.